# How could I have MySQL IN clause within my elasticsearch query?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, get, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying perform an `elasticsearch` query as a `GET` request in order pull data from the index which I created. The data which is in the index is, a table from `MySQL` DB, configured though `logstash`.

Here is my request without the IN clause:

[http://localhost:9200/response_summary/_search?q=api:"location"+AND+transactionoperationstatus:"charged"+AND+operatorid='DIALOG'+AND+userid:*test+AND+time:"2015-05-27*"](http://localhost:9200/response_summary/_search?q=api:%22location%22%20AND%20transactionoperationstatus:%22charged%22%20AND%20operatorid='DIALOG'%20AND%20userid:*test%20AND%20time:%222015-05-27*%22)

In the above, I should be able to append `AND responseCode IN (401,403)`. I tried giving it a search on the web, but couldn't find any solutions.

Any help could be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply append either of these:

- `responseCode:(401 403)`
- `responseCode:(401 OR 403)`
- `responseCode:(401 || 403)`

Like this:

```
http://localhost:9200/response_summary/_search?q=api:"location"+AND+transactionoperationstatus:"charged"+AND+operatorid='DIALOG'+AND+userid:test+AND+time:"2015-05-27"+AND+responseCode:(401+403)
```

Comment: any idea how can mysql `sum()` be appended to the above query?

Comment: Since this is a different issue, feel free to ask a new question so we don't cram too much into this one

Comment: yup sure, will post as another!