# convert SQL select query with 'IN' operator to elasticsearch search query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, nosql-aggregation, nosql

I want to convert the following SQL query to Elasticsearch search query. Can anyone help me with this, thanks.

```
Select sum(total_apples_count) 
from basket where ( apple_color in (
    select apple_color from apple_details where type = "O") || 
    apple_texture in (
        select apple_texture from apple_details where type = "O"
    ) 
);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Sami. I'm a noob when it comes to asking questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply append using `:` as such if you're using `IN`:

```
apple_color :()
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761988/how-could-i-have-mysql-in-clause-within-my-elasticsearch-query) might help you.

In order to use `SUM` within your ES query, you could do something like this within your request body:

```
"aggs":{  
          "total":{  
              "sum":{  
                  "script":"doc['total_apples_count'].value"
               }
           }
       }
```

[Ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) for aggregation of `sum`.

Comment: consider the table titles (total_apples_count, apple_details ) to be record types when it comes to elasticsearch and there are infinite counts of records in each table or data type.

the sample you linked uses static values as references like :(401 403) but in my case i have over 1,000,000 records as reference.